# Extjs4, Summary value of a grid column that even not checked(selected)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to sum of grid column. but I don't know how to get all the rows even not selected one.

For only selected I do,

```
(controller)
var sum =0;
var grid = this.getMyGrid().getSelectionModel.getSelection();

Ext.each(grid,function(item)){
  sum += item.data.qty;
}
```

but How should I do to get grid data that include not selected row too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.myGrid().store.each(function() {
...
})
```